# Android.Util.Property Class Implemention in C#

Tags: java, c#, xamarin.android

I have been banging my head for days to find some help but maybe I am not looking at the right place.

I am following this article to replicate Twitter like button animation (I don't want to use rebuilt libraries) - http://frogermcs.github.io/twitters-like-animation-in-android-alternative/

I have a Custom View called `LikeButtonView`

```
 public class LikeButtonView : FrameLayout, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        private static DecelerateInterpolator DECCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new DecelerateInterpolator();
        private static AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator ACCELERATE_DECELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
        private static OvershootInterpolator OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR = new OvershootInterpolator(4);
        private ImageView ivStar;
        private DotsView vDotsView;
       
        private AnimatorSet animatorSet;

        public LikeButtonView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
            base(context, attrs)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public LikeButtonView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
            base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            vDotsView.setCurrentProgress(0);         
            animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
            ObjectAnimator starScaleYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(ivStar, ImageView.ScaleYs, 0.2f, 1f);
            starScaleYAnimator.SetDuration(350);
            starScaleYAnimator.StartDelay = (250);
            starScaleYAnimator.SetInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator starScaleXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(ivStar, ImageView.ScaleXs, 0.2f, 1f);
            starScaleXAnimator.SetDuration(350);
            starScaleXAnimator.StartDelay = (250);
            starScaleXAnimator.SetInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator dotsAnimator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(vDotsView, DotsView.DOTS_PROGRESS, 0.2f, 1f);
            dotsAnimator.SetDuration(900);
            dotsAnimator.StartDelay = (50);
            dotsAnimator.SetInterpolator(ACCELERATE_DECELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

            animatorSet.PlayTogether(
                   starScaleYAnimator,
                   starScaleXAnimator,
                   dotsAnimator
           );
            animatorSet.Start();         
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            var INF = LayoutInflater.From(Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_like_button, this, true);
            ivStar = INF.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ivStar);
            vDotsView = INF.FindViewById<DotsView>(Resource.Id.vDotsView);           
            SetOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
```

I am also using `private DotsView vDotsView` which is another custom view, which is a C# Replica of this view https://github.com/frogermcs/LikeAnimation/blob/master/app/src/main/java/frogermcs/io/likeanimation/DotsView.java

In the above link, right at the end, I see the following

```
  public static final Property<DotsView, Float> DOTS_PROGRESS = new Property<DotsView, Float>(Float.class, "dotsProgress") {
        @Override
        public Float get(DotsView object) {
            return object.getCurrentProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void set(DotsView object, Float value) {
            object.setCurrentProgress(value);
        }
    };
```

It is Android.Util.Property getting used to `get` and `set` the progress

```
ObjectAnimator dotsAnimator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(vDotsView, DotsView.DOTS_PROGRESS, 0.2f, 1f);
```

I am lost right here, I do not know how to implement this in C#? I have been trying different things but no luck with implementing `public static final Property<DotsView, Float> DOTS_PROGRESS` with exact parameters.

If anyone can help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this helps anyone, we can do something like the following

```
[Register("DOTS_PROGRESS")]
public static Property DotsProgress {
   get {
         JniObjectReference objectValue = _members.get_StaticFields().GetObjectValue("DOTS_PROGRESS.Landroid/util/Property;");
                return Object.GetObject<Property>(objectValue.get_Handle(), 1);
       }
}
```

Found this package which was converted from java to C#
https://www.fuget.org/packages/Karamunting.Android.HanksZyh.SmallBang/1.2.2/lib/monoandroid81/SmallBang.dll/Hanks.Library.Bang/DotsView?code=true